# php explode function for only first white space

Tags: php

I have a String `Hello This is a String`. I need to explode it in PHP only for the First `White Space`. How is that possible?

Answer (score 61):

set *limit* parameter

```
print_r(explode(' ', $str, 2));
```

[`Reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 29):

yes

just call

```
explode(' ',$s, 2)
```

this will create an array with at most 2 elements

Answer (score 12):

Try

`explode(' ', $your_string, 2)`

See more: [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$str   = 'Hello This is a String';
$parts = preg_split('/(\s)/', $str, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean a space character for this answer. instead of thinking in terms of `explode()` you should think in terms of "find the first character and split the string there."

```
$pos = strpos($inputString, ' ');
$part1 = substr($inputString, 0, $pos);
$part2 = substr($inputString, $pos+1);
```