# Doctrine 2 - How to add limit in multiple addSelect

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-3

**Problem** : got **Error** when i run my query

```
{
    "status": false,
    "error": {
        "classname": "Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException",
        "message": "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 783: Error: Expected Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'LIMIT'"
    }
}
```

How can i add **limit** in **addSelect** in below query.

```
 $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select("identity(igsm.group) as group_id,
    qp.id AS q_paper_id,
    qp.name AS q_name,
    qp.description AS q_description,        
    qp.marks,
    identity(qp.questionPaperStatus) AS qpStatus,
    qp.timeInMinutes as time_in_minutes,
    sa.marks as marks_obtained,
    sa.id AS assessment_id");
    $qb->addSelect("(SELECT IfElse(count(qps.id) > 0 , TRUE, FALSE) FROM Entity\QuestionPaper qps "
            . "WHERE qps.createdBy = :userId AND qps.id = qp.id) as flag");
    $qb->addSelect("(SELECT count(qpe.id) from Entity\QuestionPaperEvaluation qpe "
            . "where qpe.questionPaper = qp.id AND qpe.user = :userId) as student_evaluation_cnt");
    $qb->addSelect("(SELECT LOWER(ats.assignee) from Entity\AssessmentTimelineStatus ats, Entity\AssessmentStudentTimeline ast "
            . "WHERE ast.assessmentTimelineStatus = ats.id AND ast.user = igsm.user AND ast.assessment = qp.id "
            . "ORDER BY ats.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS assignee");
    $qb->addSelect("(SELECT identity(ast.assessmentTimelineStatus) from Entity\AssessmentTimelineStatus ats, Entity\AssessmentStudentTimeline ast "
            . "WHERE ast.assessmentTimelineStatus = ats.id AND ast.user = igsm.user AND ast.assessment = qp.id "
            . "ORDER BY ats.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS assessment_timeline_id");
    $qb->addSelect("(SELECT UPPER(ConcatWs(' ', ats.action,ats.item)) as assesment_submissions from Entity\AssessmentTimelineStatus ats, "
            . "Entity\AssessmentStudentTimeline ast WHERE ast.assessmentTimelineStatus = ats.id AND ast.user = igsm.user AND ast.assessment = qp.id "
            . "ORDER BY ats.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS action");
    $qb->from('Entity\QuestionPaperGroupStudentMap', 'qpgsm');
    $qb->innerJoin('Entity\InstituteGroupStudentMap', 'igsm', 'WITH', 'igsm.id=qpgsm.instituteGroupStudentMap');
    $qb->innerJoin('Entity\QuestionPaper', 'qp', 'WITH', 'qp.id=qpgsm.questionPaper AND qp.questionPaperStatus > 4');
    $qb->leftJoin('Entity\AssesmentSubmissions', 'sa', 'WITH', 'sa.assesmentId = qp.id AND sa.userId = igsm.user');
    $qb->leftJoin('Entity\PackageQuestionPaperHistory', 'pqph', 'WITH', 'pqph.questionPaperId = qp.id');
    $qb->where('igsm.user = :userId')->setParameter(':userId', $userId);
    $qb->andWhere("igsm.group IN (:GroupIds)")->setParameter(':GroupIds', explode(",", $groupId));
    $qb->orderBy('qpgsm.id', 'DESC');
    $qb->setMaxResults(1);
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $result;
```

Can i put subquery individualy though Subquery is dependent on main query.
How can i add limit in my sub query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an  [issue](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/5409) about this in github.

The same question has been asked:

- [Subquery with LIMIT in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068947/subquery-with-limit-in-doctrine)
- [Doctrine 2 limit IN subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234233/doctrine-2-limit-in-subquery)

A possible **quick hack solution** could be to:

- Prepend the **desired select** column with the **"order by" column** in the select statement
- use **MIN or MAX** to aggregate the results to just get the 1st one(to have the same result as LIMIT 1)

This subselect:

```
$qb->addSelect("(SELECT LOWER(ats.assignee) from Entity\AssessmentTimelineStatus ats, Entity\AssessmentStudentTimeline ast "
        . "WHERE ast.assessmentTimelineStatus = ats.id AND ast.user = igsm.user AND ast.assessment = qp.id "
        . "ORDER BY ats.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS assignee");
```

would be written as:

```
$qb->addSelect("(SELECT MAX(concat(ats.id, ' ', LOWER(ats.assignee))) from Entity\AssessmentTimelineStatus ats, Entity\AssessmentStudentTimeline ast "
        . "WHERE ast.assessmentTimelineStatus = ats.id AND ast.user = igsm.user AND ast.assessment = qp.id "
        . "ORDER BY ats.id DESC) AS assignee");
```

When you get the "assignee" value, you can split to the 1st single whitespace value and get the value of "LOWER(ats.assignee)".

```
$result = explode(' ',$assignee, 2);
```

Use MAX when the ORDER BY is DESC and MIN when ASC.

This works because MAX or MIN aggregate function **select only the highest or lowest value**, which can be either a number or a string.

References

[MAX/MIN mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max)

[explode to 1st whitespace character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402263/php-explode-function-for-only-first-white-space)